# "Authentication credentials were not provided." in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using **rest_framework_simplejwt** authentication in my DRF backend. Everything works absolutely fine when I am using the DRF browser in terms of authentication and having access to predefined API endpoints.

However, when I want to programmatically access the endpoints for the post/patch method I get *Authentication credentials were not provided.* error.
Here is my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'propertypost.apps.PropertyConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'rest_framework',

    # 3rd party
    'django_filters',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'django.contrib.gis',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}


...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=525600),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=120),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

REST_USE_JWT = True
```

as I said, above setting works perfectly in DRF browser, but when here when I try to request a patch method it gives  **Authentication credentials were not provided**:

```
AUTH_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login"
    
data = {
       'username': username,
        'password': password
headers = {
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
 r = requests.post(AUTH_ENDPOINT, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
  token=r.json()['token']
 data = {
        'age': 8,
    }
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "JWT " + token,
}
    
r = requests.patch(POST_ENDPOINT, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**Usage** section](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#usage), the headers must be in the following format

```
"Authorization: Bearer YourToken"
```

So, Change your headers to,

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
}
```